# iPad app not listed in multitasking split view list

Tags: ios9, split-screen-multitasking

I try to enable my existing universal iOS app for multitasking (split view), but it's not listed there, although I fulfill all requirements, I guess:

- it's universal
- iPhone and iPad app support all orientations (is this necessary for the iPhone app as well?)
- built with the latest Xcode, base SDK version iOS 9
- LaunchScreen.storyboard is used

What else could I be missing?

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Did you find any solution or that already?

Comment: for me, it was the `requires fullscreen` option which was activated

Comment: Thank you and why don't you answer you own question?

Comment: sorry - did it now!

Comment: You can mark as a right answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved the problem; it was the `Requires full screen` checkbox:
[image]

After ticking it off, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to delete `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad` and associated array values from my info plist file - but leave the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` one.